# Measuring gravity using (only) pendulums and rulers

Tags: gravity, time, measurements, oscillators

[Kater's pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kater%27s_pendulum#Experimental_procedure) was used to measure the local force of gravity. However, the procedure was to time it by using a standard pendulum clock!

> To use, the pendulum was hung from a bracket on a wall, with the knife blade pivots supported on two small horizontal agate plates, in front of a precision pendulum clock to time the period.

How does this give a measure of the period, as the clock’s own pendulum will be affected by the local gravity value too?

Comment: Are you using a pendulum clock to do the timing?

Comment: If the pendulum clock is calibrated to another time standard, e.g. the length of the solar day, then it's OK. It's simply a secondary standard in that case and one has to be aware of its drift and location dependence and re-calibrate accordingly.

Comment: They did not need to use a simple pendulum to measure the period of the Kater pendulum. In 19th century (Kater pendulum was invented in 1817) there was already spring-driven clocks. Some of them did not have a pendulum so they are not influenced by gravity. Moreover it would be possible to use even less accurate devices to measure the period. For example a horizontal spring-mass system which also has period independent of gravity. To overcome the inaccuracy of such device, instead of measuring the period you would measure the time of 10 or maybe 100 oscillations.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that your objection is valid.

The wikipedia article is not clear about this matter.  I think the disappointingly trivial answer must be that the local pendulum is calibrated against astronomical measurements of time.

Comment: Thanks.  I think the article has more problems with the description of the device, too.